# Why $f(x)=|x(x-1)^3|$ is derivable in $x=1$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I know that the function $f(x)=|x(x-1)^3|$ is not derivable in $x=0$, but why is it derivable in $x=1$?

Comment: graph it ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f(x)=|x|(x-1)^2|x-1|$ whence

$$
f'(1)=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{f(x)}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to1} |x|(x-1)|x-1|=0.
$$
since $|x|(x-1)|x-1|$ is a product of continuous functions.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x) = |x|\;|(x-1)^3|$. $|x|$ certainly has a derivative 1 at $x=1$, and $h(x)=|(x-1)^3|$ indeed has a derivative at $x=1$ too. $$
h'(1)=\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}\frac{h(x)-h(1)}{x-1}=\frac{|(x-1)^3|}{x-1}$$
But $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^+}\frac{|(x-1)^3|}{x-1}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^+}(x-1)^2=0$$
and $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^-}\frac{|(x-1)^3|}{x-1}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^+}-(x-1)^2=0$$
Hence $h'(1)=0$. Note that this method cannot be applied to $|x-1|$ at $x=1$. For intuitions, look at the pictures of $|x-1|$ and $|(x-1)^3|$.